# spring-boot application without a datasource

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to create a spring-boot application that has NO datasource? In my case i just need a simple REST app but it seems on start up that there is an attempt to auto initialise a datasource

My pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>a.b.c.d.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-customer-builder</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>rest-customer-builder</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <!--<relativePath/> lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My application.properties is

```
server.contextPath=/rest-customer-builder
server.port=9090
```

When i run

```
mvn clean install spring-boot:run
```

i see this error

```
015-08-18 14:54:31.870  INFO 12530 --- [lication.main()] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2015-08-18 14:54:31.903  WARN 12530 --- [lication.main()] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/geronimo/osgi/locator/ProviderLocator
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.bearingpoint.eircom.test.rest.customerbuilder.RestCustomerBuilderApplication.main(RestCustomerBuilderApplication.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/geronimo/osgi/locator/ProviderLocator
    at javax.validation.Validation$DefaultValidationProviderResolver.getValidationProviders(Validation.java:209)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:173)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$Jsr303ValidatorFactory.run(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:381)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.geronimo.osgi.locator.ProviderLocator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Can you please show your pom.xml file or the gradle equivalent

Comment: You must have more on the classpath than you've listed in the pom. `Jsr303ValidatorFactory` will only run if you've got the various `javax.validation` classes on the classpath. It also looks like you've got something on the classpath that contains metadata pointing to `org/apache/geronimo/osgi/locator/ProviderLocator`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable all Database related auto configuration in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387265/disable-all-database-related-auto-configuration-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

It is possible to run a spring boot application without datasource.
You must disable the auto configuration for the datasource and may be for JPA also :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

The exception you posted is something else, as written in the comments, you have something in the classpath that references the missing class of apache geronimo.
So you must get rid of the code/jar that references geronimo or add geronimo to your dependencies.

Comment: This worked for me. I only had to exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: What about if I want to re-enable spring AutoConfiguration after I excluded it, because I've created a DataBase and I have a jdbc url connection?

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me, but as I'm using Spring Boot, I had to add the exclusions via the @SpringBootApplication annotation itself, like this:

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})

Answer (score 34):

A better way to fix this point will be to remove the dependencies from your POM/Gradle configuration file and Spring Boot will not try to auto configure the DataSource.

Comment: e.g. if you're using Spring boot, remove "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" from your dependencies.

Comment: Removing org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa from the POM did the trick, thanks

Comment: IMHO the right way regarding NO datasource - and for example just add spring-boot-starter-web for a main class extending SpringBootServletInitializer.

Answer (score 17):

@Stefan +1 
If you are using YAML file for configuration this is how it is

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
    - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
    - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

It worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue, Once I have removed below dependency it started working.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

as for Spring Boot current version (2.5.4) you can put it on the @SpringBootApplication annotation
like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class YourApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically I did the same thing as @Rocky wrote above in .properties file and it works.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score -6):

Provide spring.datasource.url in the application.properties file. It worked for me.
Example: 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/Test_DB

Comment: It's mentioned that no data source needed, so definitely no need to add configuration for mysql.