# Just running project from start.spring with error

Tags: java, spring

Im downloading project from  start.spring.io with Maven Java 2.0.0 with Web,JPA,Vaadin. 
Opening it in Intellij with Java SDK 9, pressing run, and having this error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-06 18:25:17.342 ERROR 1768 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Answer (score 0):

Certain default Spring Boot configurations must have a Bean of type `javax.sql.DataSource`. If there are multiple `DataSource` implementations defined, one of them must be declared `primary`.

Failing that, Spring will default to looking up an existing database based on several properties. See the part of [this webpage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) titled "Connection to a Production Database".

Comment: so what i should do after downloading project? In youtube guides they just download from spring.start and running it

Comment: Then you have to specifically exclude the datasource configuration. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074631/spring-boot-application-without-a-datasource).

Answer (score 0):

Could be late, but it might be useful for others.

I faced this issue, when trying to connect PostgreSql DB from spring boot application. I had resources "< resources >" filter in pom.xml which filtered out few of the sql files which are needed. When I removed that the error has gone.