# How to configure Spring Boot to not connect to database

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, datasource

**Please note:** this question is *not* a dupe, and I even reference the other similar question below. I assert that my situation is categorically different than the other question referenced.

---

I am standing up a Spring Boot web service that is *not* backed by any database, JDBC or RDBMS data source.

At startup I get and error:

```
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
```

Here on SO I see a [very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074749/spring-boot-cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type) where the accepted answer states:

> "*You haven't provided Spring Boot with enough information to auto-configure a `DataSource`*"

...and goes on to explain how to set the appropriate values in the app config file:

```
spring.datasource.url = ...
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = ...
```

**But what if I don't want *any* data sources?!** In the other question, the user was connecting to NoSQL via DataNucleus. In my case, I'm not interested (at least at the present moment) in connecting to *any* type of data source (all data for this service will come from other cloud-based REST services).

What's the fix here?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074631/spring-boot-application-without-a-datasource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration), you can turn this behavior off by excluding `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` from the auto-configuration that Spring Boot does for you.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

**Update To Answer Questions**: By using `@SpringBootApplication`, it automatically pulls in `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and if it sees the jdbc jars on the classpath, will add/execute `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. The code above turns off this behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Todd (+1) but I'm not following -- I don't have any classes annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in my whole project, nor do I have any `spring.datasource.*` properties defined in my config file...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @SpringBootApplication decorator you can exclude by using the DataSourceAutoConfiguration as done in the @EnableAutoConfiguration decorator as well. [Documentation ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.auto-configuration.disabling-specific)

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyApplication {
// ...
}
```